# Using date from one table in a where clause with a column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables in my query. My goal is to use the `start date` and `end date` dynamically in the `where` clause such that the two tables are joined using `inner join`

```
where MD_SettlementDate between 'MI_startDate' and 'MI_enddate'
```

For every MI_ID, the query should use the MI_Startdate and MI_Enddate to do a `sum(MD_consumption)`

Table 1 (MI):

| MI_ID | Column2 | MI_StartDate | MI_EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | info | 2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | info | 2018-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-08-30 00:00:00.000 |

Table 2: The following table has half hour interval data.

| MD_ID | Consumption | MD_SettlementDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 34 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 123 | 54 | 2020-07-01 00:30:00.000 |
| 124 | 43 | 2020-07-01 01:00:00.000 |

Comment: So what do you need help with? And please show us your expected results for the given sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use a `where` clause, just a `join`:

```
select . . . -- whatever columns you want
from mi join
     table2 t2
     on t2.MD_SettlementDate between mi.MI_startDate and mi.MI_enddate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Table1.MI_ID,
    (
        SELECT SUM(MD_consumption)
        FROM Table2
        WHERE MD_SettlementDate BETWEEN Table1.MI_startDate and Table1.MI_enddate
    ) AS SumOfMD_consumption
FROM Table1
```